# Search for a table within a database in Laravel 4 PHP Framework

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to set up search for a table within database in mine within the Laravel 4 PHP Framework.  I am using jquery to accomplish this.  I have a table "artists", that I am trying to allow a user to search through.  I have a  model "Artist.php", and a controller "SearchController.php" that I am using to control the logic.  Finally, I have a view "search.blade.php" that I am using as the user facing file.  Here is the relevant code:

SearchController.php:

```
public function show_search() {

    $limit = 10;

        if(isset($_GET['mode']) && !empty($_GET['mode'])) {
            switch($_GET['mode']) {
                case 'autocomplete':
                    if(isset($_GET['keywords']) && !empty($_GET['keywords'])) {

                        $query = htmlspecialchars($_GET['keywords']);
                        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

                        $results = Artist::search_artists($query);

                        $data = array();
                        $i = 0;
                        if(isset($results) && !empty($results)) {
                            foreach($results as $result) {
                                if (strlen(strstr($result->stage_name, 'artists')) == 0) {
                                    if($i < $limit) {
                                        $data[$i] = $result;
                                        $i++;
                                    }
                                }                                                
                            }
                        }
                        exit;
                    }                    
                break;
                }
        }       
        return View::make('search.search');
    }
```

Artist.php:

```
public static function search_artists($query) {
        $search_artists = DB::table('artists')
                        ->where('artists.stage_name', 'LIKE', $query)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->get();

        return $search_artists;
    }
```

search.blade.php:

```
<input type="text" class="search" id="inputSearch" /><br /> 
<div id="divResult"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        $(".search").keyup(function() { 
            var inputSearch = $(this).val();
            var data        = {mode : 'autocomplete', keywords : inputSearch};

            if(inputSearch!='') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/search/search",
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        console.log(html);
                        $("#divResult").html(html).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

I call all of this with the route:

```
Route::get('/search/search', array('uses' => 'SearchController@show_search'));
```

When I run this and I type things into the search box, I see in the javascript console it reads:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

and the results don't display under the search box.  Any idea what could be going wrong?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript warning is caused by your `return false;`. If you need it (doesn't seem necessary for the `keyup` event unless you want to catch the enter key), you should do something like:

```
$(".search").keyup(function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();    // prevent the default action of the event
```

I am not familiar with Laravel, but it seems to me that you are not getting any results because you are not doing anything with the `$data` variable in your controller.

I would guess you need something similar to:

```
return View::make('search.search', $data);
```

to pass the variable to your view.

Comment: hmm, I changed the return false; to e.preventDefault(); and it is still giving me this error

Comment: Also, could you expound on the second part?  I am already trying to display the data using: success: function(html) {
                        console.log(html);
                        $("#divResult").html(html).show();
                    }

Comment: @user1072337 Have you removed the `return false;`? About the view, it should echo / output what you need in the javascript, that will be your `html` variable (everything your view echoes out).

Comment: I did remove the return false; I also changed the controller to read: return View::make('search.search', array('results' => $data)); and now it says "undefined variable $data"

Comment: @user1072337 You need to put the `return` statement of your view before the `exit;` statement. What does your view look like exactly?

Comment: it just has the input box for the search; also if you look at the code for the controller, it won't create the data or go inside that section until there is a keyup event, which means it will first create the view that is made at the bottom.

Comment: @user1072337 You need to return the data to the javascript one way or another, either via a view or via an `echo json_encode($data);`.

Comment: Could you please show me how you would do this in the context of the code I have already?